# Three.js - How to slowly change the camera's orientation untill it reaches a specific vector

Tags: three.js, camera, tween.js

I'm using Three.js to develop a player for 360° pictures, and I need some advice.

I have created a few cliquable meshs inside the scene. Currently, when the user clicks on a mesh, the camera's orientation is brutally changed to the mesh's direction. (this done by calling THREE.Camera.lookat()).

What I want is that when the users clicks, the camera transitions smoothly from it's target vector to the mesh's direction. I would like that the camera takes about 1 second to go from its current vector to the mesh's direction.

I have seen that tween is a library with which we can animate the scene, but I didn't really understand how it works. 
Do you know what I could use to implement this animation ?
If tween can help me, can you explain how tween comes into play with three.js, or can you link some githubs or else ?

Thank you for feedbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an extension of the manthrax's idea with Tween.js

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, 32, 24), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "yellow",
  wireframe: true
}));
scene.add(sphere);

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var startRotation = new THREE.Quaternion();
var targetRotation = new THREE.Quaternion();
window.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown, false);

function onMouseDown(event) {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  let newPosition = raycaster.ray.at(10);
  setPoint(newPosition);

  // manthrax's idea + Tween.js
  startRotation.copy(camera.quaternion);
  camera.lookAt(newPosition);
  camera.updateMatrixWorld();
  targetRotation = camera.quaternion.clone();
  camera.quaternion.copy(startRotation);

  new TWEEN.Tween(camera.quaternion).to(targetRotation, 1000).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Bounce.Out).delay(250).start();
  // one of benefits of using Tween.js is easings
  // you can find many of them here
  // https://sole.github.io/tween.js/examples/03_graphs.html

}

function setPoint(position) {
  let point = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.125, 4, 2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: "red",
    wireframe: true
  }));
  point.position.copy(position);
  scene.add(point);
}

render()

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  TWEEN.update(); // don't forget to put this line into the animation loop, when you use Tween.js
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/91/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tween.js/17.2.0/Tween.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for that great tutorial. It's been perfect, everything i needed to integrate. I ended up using Cubic.InOut.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var targetRotation,startTime,transitionDuration;
var startRotation = camera.quaternion.clone();

function smoothTransition(newTarget){
    startRotation.copy(camera.quaternion);
    camera.lookAt(newTarget);
    camera.updateMatrixWorld();
    targetRotation = camera.rotation.clone();
    startTime = performance.now();
    transitionDuration = 1000;
}
```

In animate:

```
if(startRotation){
    var playTime = (performance.now()-startTime)/transitionDuration;
    if(playTime>1)playTime = 1;
    Quaternion.slerp(startRotation,targetRotation,camera.rotation,playTime);
    camera.updateMatrixWorld();
}
```